# A medical notation which i could not understand

Tags: cardiology, prescription

My doctor (a cardiologist) always writes this in his prescription after checking his patients:

```
A.C.J.U.NV.NJ.O.
```

Please note all the dots will be superscripts.

What does this mean?

Comment: I think this question is much better suited for health.se, I will migrate it.

Comment: I'm not being able to use math jax formatting. Please anyone help....

Comment: don't bother if it doesn't work.

Comment: @AliceD  Wish that others will understand...

Comment: I think Mathjax is not implemented on this site.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you just asked him?

Comment: It's not an abbreviation I'm familiar with either.

Comment: Please let us know if you come to know the full form.